# Tool that measures single command CPU/Memory usage?

Tags: linux, profile

Are there any usefull tools that can measure the CPU/Memory usage of a single command?

I want something like:

```
cpu_mem_perf some_executable args1 args2
```

and `cpu_mem_perf`  will print the CPU/Memory usage of the command `some_executable args1 args2` after execution, that is, the total CPU/Memory usage of process runing `some_executable args1 args2` and processes forked by `some_executable args1 args2`

Comment: You need the info reported when the task has competed or the info displayed periodically while the task is running ?

Comment: @MC68020 I want the info when the job is done, in fact, I only need the max CPU/Memory usage of the job during execution.

Comment: @konchy it sounds like you're envisioning a tool that takes samples of the current cpu consumption while the process runs, calculating the average and maximum from the samples, and reports those when the process finishes.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @SottoVoce yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [GNU version of the *time* utility](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Time) with some custom format :

Something like `time --format="%E %M" some_executable` might well basically fit your needs, but do check the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) (starting from the *Gnu version* paragraph) in order to discover the possibility to print many other cpu and memory usage details that would better fit for you.

BTW, reports will include some_executable 's children activity.

Note that this software is almost certainly made available via your package manager.

---

**About some CPU usage "*peak*" value**, (following OP's comments hereafter) :

GNU time utility does not report *peak* values which would require the utility to periodically sample /proc in a *top*-like way.
Needless since… this value is already highly predictable, if not certain  (as anyone can at sometimes instantly read using *top*) : **100%**
which is nothing but logical since, per design, once a task is scheduled in, it will use 100% of the cpu running this task.

In OP's precise need, more meaningful would be some ***average*** given by the %P parameter of the format string.

Comment: thanks, it satisfies most of my needs, but `time` seems not recording the `max` or `peak` cpu usage of the executable

Comment: @konchy : For the max, aren't %S and %U what you are precisely looking for since max should logically be the grand total at completion. About peak, you are correct but, would it be meaningful since the utility would need to periodically sample some kernel data, this inducing error in the report not to say not reporting the real peak value. (cf top / htop problems in being accurate in that area)

Comment: I want to use estimated `peak` cpu usage of the program to decide allocating how many cpus(as a docker container) or which machine to run the program, so even it's based on sampled data and not that precise, it's ok, it will be usefull for me

Comment: @konchy : Of course you know that at any given time some_executable is scheduled in, cpu usage of the elected CPU for this precise task is… necessarily… : 100%.

Comment: @konchy : What I mean is what you are probably looking for is not the "peak" value (predictably being 100%) but most probably some average. In which case, it would seem that the %P format is what you want.

Comment: sorry for I may not make it clear enough, for "samples" like output of top/htop, we can get the averge cpu usage of a very small period(say 0.1sec or 1sec interval), and I want a tool to auto calculate the maximun of these "averge values"

Comment: and if the sample interval is very small, we'll indeed get 100%, it's acutally meaningless, I may only care about max value of average cpu usage based on 1s or 0.5s sample intervals